# How can i set XMLHttpRequest to support Unicode when it pass data by QueryString?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I use regular XmlHttlRequest, everything work fine except the unicode.
How can i set that the query string will support unicode, (right now it return to c# '??????' when i pass unicode character (Hebrew)). I've tried to set the globalization setting to UTF-16 or Unicode in the web.config like this:

But it still pass '????'.

I attach pic of my code although its a XmlHttpRequest regular code like everyone know.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Believe it or not but people answering you sometimes want to copy&paste your code ;). Please don't post code as an image, instead paste the actual code and mark it up properly (this site will do syntax highlighting automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest won't modify URLs (other than removing invalid characters), you have to build the correct URL yourself. That's what `encodeURIComponent` function is good for:

```
xmlRequest.open("GET", "foo.apx?name=" + encodeURIComponent(name));
```

Comment: This is solve the problem, Now its work fine. Thank you very much !